# How does this algorithm to calculate square root work?

Tags: c++, math

I have found a piece of mathematical code to compute the square root of a real value. I obviously understand the code itself, but I must say that I badly understand the math logic of that algorithm. How does it work exactly?

```
inline
double _recurse(const double &_, const double &_x, const double &_y)
 
        { double _result;
 
          if(std::fabs(_y - _x) > 0.001)
            _result = _recurse(_, _y, 0.5 * (_y + _ / _y));
          else
            _result = _y;
 
          return _result;
        }

inline 
double sqrt(const double &_) 

       { return _recurse(_, 1.0, 0.5 * (1.0 + _)); }
```

Comment: Look up "Newton's method".

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method gave me the answer... Many thanks

Comment: Please don't have variables named `_`.

Comment: ok... no more _ for next posts

Comment: This is actually Heron's Method: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_method

Answer (score 2):

Assume that you want to compute `√a` and have found an approxmation `x`. You want to improve that approximation by adding some correction `δ` to `x`. In other terms, you want to establish

```
x + δ = √a
```

or

```
(x + δ)² = x² + 2xδ + δ² = a
```

If you neglect the small term `δ²`, you can solve for `δ` and get

```
δ ~ (a - x²)/(2x)
```

and finally

```
x + δ ~ (a + x²)/(2x) = (a/x + x)/2.
```

This process can be iterated and converges very quickly to `√a`.

---

E.g. for `a=2` and the initial value `x=1`, we get the approximations

```
1, 3/2, 17/12, 577/408, 665857/470832, ...
```

and the corresponding squares,

```
1, 2.25, 2.00694444..., 2.0000060073049..., 2.0000000000045...
```